# How to get PC name (with/without Domain) in Oracle APEX #orclapex in non-IE browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Edge)

Tags: javascript, sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I wantto fetch the computer name/hostname of the client PC.

My javascript code is something like this which works in IE

```
function GetComputerName() {
  try {
    var network = new ActiveXObject('WScript.Network');
    alert(network.computerName);
  }
  catch (e) { }
}
```

I also understand that this will not work in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari, etc.
Also tried calling a Java stored procedure from a PL/SQL function as below

```
import java.net.*;
public class Test {
  public static String getHost () {
    try {
      String hostname = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName();
      return hostname;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      return "Could not find Hostname! Error!";
    }
  }
}
```

But the output here is 127.0.0.1. Plus, I am executing this piece of Java code over an Oracle database, so I suppose the code will return the hostname of the server.

> Thought: Is it possible to invoke an IE object from a chrome (or any other modern browser) session, and invoke the ActiveXObject object for that? I googled but found no such implementations.

I am open to alternative implementations as well (as long as the computer name can be fetched in a non-IE browser)

Comment: `Is it possible to invoke an IE object from a chrome (or any other modern browser) session` - no, thankfully - even Microsoft Edge doesn't "do" ActiveX - the local computer name is not something a browser should need to expose to a web page ... **never**

Comment: I understand that this is a matter of security, but then how do you access OS level properties such as "Computer Name" from the scope of the browser.

Comment: you cant. why does your web page need to do that?

Comment: We have a client application which stores the username and hostname in the database every time a user logs into the application :) This works only in IE (obviously) but now I am looking to remove this dependency

Comment: oh, so this is purely client side code? page is served locally, not through the internet?

Comment: yes, that's correct